# Python/Pandas: use one column's value to be the suffix of the column name from which I want a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, processing-efficiency

I have a pandas dataframe. From multiple columns therein, I need to select the value from only one into a single new column, according to the ID (`bar` in this example) of that row.
I need the fastest way to do this.

Dataframe for application is like this:

```
foo bar ID_A    ID_B    ID_C    ID_D    ID_E    ...
1   B   1.5     2.3     4.1     0.5     6.6     ...
2   E   3       4       5       6       7       ...
3   A   9       6       3       8       1       ...
4   C   13      5       88      9       0       ...
5   B   6       4       6       9       4       ...
...
```

An example of a way to do it (my fastest at present) is thus - however, it is too slow for my purposes.

```
df.loc[df.bar=='A', 'baz'] = df.ID_A
df.loc[df.bar=='B', 'baz'] = df.ID_B
df.loc[df.bar=='C', 'baz'] = df.ID_C
df.loc[df.bar=='D', 'baz'] = df.ID_D
df.loc[df.bar=='E', 'baz'] = df.ID_E
df.loc[df.bar=='F', 'baz'] = df.ID_F
df.loc[df.bar=='G', 'baz'] = df.ID_G
```

Result will be like this (after dropping used columns):

```
foo baz
1   2.3
2   7
3   9
4   88
5   4
...
```

I have tried with `.apply()` and it was very slow.
I tried with `np.where()` which was still much slower than the example shown above (which was 1000% faster than `np.where()`).

Would appreciate recommendations!
Many thanks

EDIT: after the first few answers, I think I need to add this:
"whilst I would appreciate runtime estimate relative to the example, I know it's a small example so may be tricky.
My actual data has 280000 rows and an extra 50 columns (which I need to keep along with `foo` and `baz`). I have to reduce 13 columns to the single column per the example.
The speed is the only reason for asking, & no mention of speed thus far in first few responses. Thanks again!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a variant of the [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize('ID_'+df['bar'])
out = pd.DataFrame({'foo': df['foo'],
                    'baz': df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]})
```

output:

```
   foo   baz
0    1   2.3
1    2   7.0
2    3   9.0
3    4  88.0
4    5   4.0
```

#### testing speed

Setting up a test dataset (280k rows, 54 ID columns):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase

letters = list(ascii_lowercase+ascii_uppercase)
N = 280_000

np.random.seed(0)

df = (pd.DataFrame({'foo': np.arange(1, N+1),
                    'bar': np.random.choice(letters, size=N)})
        .join(pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(N, len(letters))),
                           columns=[f'ID_{l}' for l in letters]
                          ))
     )
```

speed testing:

```
%%timeit
idx, cols = pd.factorize('ID_'+df['bar'])
out = pd.DataFrame({'foo': df['foo'],
                    'baz': df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]})
```

output:

```
54.4 ms ± 3.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: @DanielThomas speed testing is tricky if you don't know the real data. A simple number of columns/rows is not sufficient. Please provide a dummy dataframe for testing. Use `np.random` to generate an arbitrary big dataset. Don't forget to seed the generator: `np.random.seed(0)` immediately before generation to have a reproducible dataset for everyone.

Comment: Regarding the extra column it's easy. Once you solved the issue, just join them back. This should not matter for this problem. With my proposed solution you can also just assign `df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]` to any column for in place modification.

Comment: Thanks for the last bit @mozway. Spot on, this is super-fast :D. Checked as right answer. the "assign ... to any column" bit I mean

Answer (score 0):

Can try this. It should generalize to arbitrary number of columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'B', 1.5, 2.3, 4.1, 0.5, 6.6],
      [2, 'E', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
      [3, 'A', 9, 6, 3, 8, 1],
      [4, 'C', 13, 5, 88, 9, 0],
      [5, 'B', 6, 4, 6, 9, 4]])

df.columns = ['foo', 'bar', 'ID_A', 'ID_B', 'ID_C', 'ID_D', 'ID_E']

for val in np.unique(df['bar'].values):
    df.loc[df.bar==val, 'baz'] = df[f'ID_{val}']
```

Answer (score 0):

To show an alternative approach, you can perform a combination of melting your data and reindexing. In this case I used `wide_to_long` (instead of melt/stack) because of the patterned nature of your column names:

```py
out = (
    pd.wide_to_long(
        df, stubnames=['ID'], i=['foo', 'bar'], j='', sep='_', suffix=r'\w+'
    )
    .loc[lambda d: 
        d.index.get_level_values('bar') == d.index.get_level_values(level=-1),
        'ID'
    ]
    .droplevel(-1)
    .rename('baz')
    .reset_index()
)

print(out)
   foo bar   baz
0    1   B   2.3
1    2   E   7.0
2    3   A   9.0
3    4   C  88.0
4    5   B   4.0
```

---

An alternative syntax to the above leverages `.melt` & `.query` to shorten the syntax.

```py
out = (
    df.melt(id_vars=['foo', 'bar'], var_name='id', value_name='baz')
    .assign(id=lambda d: d['id'].str.get(-1))
    .query('bar == id')
)

print(out)
    foo bar id   baz
2     3   A  A   9.0
5     1   B  B   2.3
9     5   B  B   4.0
13    4   C  C  88.0
21    2   E  E   7.0
```